# Google Maps API doesn't shows after loading in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, backbone.js

I am loading a simpel google maps frame inside a template with underscore and backbone. Almost everything loads fine. But the map doesn't shows up in the div. When i inspect the code in chrome i see the loaded google maps frame inside the div but it stays blank in the page. If you see the problem please explain.

```
/**
 * Google maps model
 */
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone){
    var MapModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            id: '',
            LatLng: {},
            mapOptions: {},
            position: {},
            map: {},
            zoom: 10,
            maxZoom: 16,
            minZoom: 12
        },
        //initialize for google maps
        initMap: function(position){
            this.set('position', position)
            var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            this.set('LatLng', LatLng);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: this.get('zoom'),
                minZoom: this.get('minZoom'),
                maxZoom: this.get('maxZoom'),
                center: this.get('LatLng'),
                mapTypeControl: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            this.set('mapOptions', mapOptions);
        }
    });

    return MapModel;
});

/**
 * google maps view
 */
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone){
    var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
        id: "",
        //initialize google maps with the model
        initialize: function(model, id){
            this.id = id;
            //set the map object into the model
            this.model.set('map', new google.maps.Map(this.el, this.model.get('mapOptions')));
        },
        //render google maps bij replacing the id with the element
        render: function(){
            var id = this.objToString(this.id);
            $('#' + id).replaceWith(this.el);
            return this;
        },
        objToString: function(obj){
            var str = '';
            for (var p in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    str += obj[p] + '\n';
                }
            }
            return str;
        }
    });

    return MapView;
});
```

The id inside the google maps view is generated from outside

```
//create model
var map_model = new MapModel();
map_model.initMap({ coords: {latitude: 52, longitude: 5} });

//set the model to the view
var map_view = new MapView({model: map_model}, {id: data[0].hashtag});

//render Google Maps
map_view.render();

//html
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
       <div class="task">
          <div id="<%= task.hashtag.replace('#', '') %>" class="google-maps" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>

       </div>
</div>

//css
.task, .google-maps {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Solution: I have found a solution for the problem with Google-maps not showing. The element in the initialize function needs a class that has a 100% width and height. The parent  will also need a width and height. In mij application i gave it 300px width and height.
code:

```
    id: "",
    collection: "",
    //initialize google maps with the model
    initialize: function(model, id, markerCollection){
        var self = this;
        this.id = '#' + this.objToString(id);
        this.collection = markerCollection;

        $(this.el).addClass('google-maps img-responsive');

        //set the map object into the model
        this.model.set('map', new google.maps.Map(this.el, this.model.get('mapOptions')));

        //update the google maps object for new markers and sizes
        $(document).ready(function () {

            setInterval(function(){
                google.maps.event.trigger(self.el, "resize");
            }, 2000);

        });

        this.addMarkers();
    },
    //render google maps bij replacing the id with the element
    render: function(){
        $(this.id).replaceWith(this.el);

        return this;
    },
    addMarkers: function(){
```

Comment: can you get the javascript on google chrome that's generated by underscore template?

Comment: hello so jin ee, i have found a solution for it after testing a lot. The css was the problem. thanks for your reply. i will update the issue for people that have the same problem.